# Outlook 2011 - my personal folders have disappeared

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2011

Does anyone know how to restore personal folders in Outlook 2011?

To clarify, both the messages and the folders have disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Hold down "Option" while launching Outlook. Check the consistency of your Database. If need be rebuild it.

Answer (score 1):

Inside Outlook, go to

```
File -> Open -> Open Outlook Data File
```

then open the folder named Personal Folder

Answer (score 0):

If you know where they are located, you can simply use File > Data File Management > Add, and browse to where they are.

If you don't know where they are, you could search for any *.pst files, or the Mac equivalent, and then use Data File Management to re-add them.

What happened prior to them disappearing?  Are any other programs impacted?

Comment: I cant find File>Data Management; does it exist on the MAc 2011 Outlook? Also i don't think there are .pst files. If you can help me further I would really appreciate it; there are important messages I can't afford to lose in my personal folders!